# Pandas, I get dataframe full of nan when reading from xlsx

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am reading from an Excel file ".xslx", it's consist of 3 columns, but when I read from it, I get a DF full of nans, I checked the table in Excel, it consists of normal cells no formulas no hyperlinks.

My code:

```
data = pd.read_excel("Data.xlsx")
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["subreddit_group", "links/caption", "subreddits/flair"])
print(df)
```

Here is the excel file:

[image: Excel file.]

Here is the output:

[image: output]

Comment: your columns in the `pd.DataFrame` call don’t match the columns from the file. You should also add the ^caption part (and you can remove them later with [`.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html))

Comment: Also for future questions, please [don’t post images of data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). It’s more useful for everyone, and you probably would have seen your error when copying and pasting the excel contents.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I see where I got it wrong, and I will keep that in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **column** parameter of `pd.Dataframe()` function doesn't set column names in result dataframe, but selects columns from the original file.

See [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) :

> Column labels to use for resulting frame when data does not have them, defaulting to RangeIndex(0, 1, 2, …, n). If data contains column labels, will perform column selection instead.

So you shouldn't provide `column` parameter and after the file is read, rename columns of the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['subreddit_group', 'links/caption', 'def']
```